# how to fix taskScheduler OnUnobservedException xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using application-level taskUnObservedErrorhandler.to handle the missed error. But I'm using try catch everywhere why I'm getting this exception. How to solve this please guide

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;`

Comment: When debugging in Visual Studio, sometimes the Output window reveals some hidden gems

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8).

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on tasks, the .NET Framework 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions. Although unobserved exceptions still raise the UnobservedTaskException exception, the process does not terminate by default.Instead, the exception is handled by the runtime after the event is raised, regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.This behavior can be configured. Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, you can use the  configuration element to revert to the behavior of the .NET Framework 4 and terminate the process:

```
 <configuration>   
   <runtime>   
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="false"/>
   </runtime>   
</configuration>
```

Comment: how to do in xamarin??

Comment: If I'm honest, I've read over the tag "xamarin.forms". But when you search for `UnobservedTaskException` in connection with `xamarin` there often appears the name `HockeyApp`. Do you use `HockeyApp`? If you do, this could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of your task is throwing an exception that is not handled which is why it ends in TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException. You either have to find where the exception is thrown or you can silently ignore it (if you know what you're doing): just set the exception as being observed.

```
private void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.SetObserved();
            LogException(e.Exception as Exception);
        }
```

Sadly you can't do that for CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException. When an exception makes it there, it's too late and you app will be killed but at least you have a chance to log the problem.